# Is there a y-offset for legend keys (markers) in python matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, key, legend

I have a plot with multiline legend labels and want to place each legend key in front of its label's first line. For scatter plots there is a workaround with `scatteryoffsets`. How to do it for other types of plots?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(1, 1, label='this is too long\n for only one line')
plt.legend(scatteryoffsets=[1.8])
plt.show()
```